# multiple structures in a file c

Tags: c, file, struct

I need to save a file that contains multiple structure data but not in a defined order.

Sample structs:

```
typedef struct {
   int a;
   char b;
} StructA_t;

typedef struct {
   CUSTOM_t a;
   char *b;
} StructB_t;

typedef struct {
   long a;
   short b;
} StructC_t;
```

The file contents struct:

```
typedef struct {
   int iStructType; // how can I get this??
   void *vpStructDatas;
   char *pNextStruct; // not necessary, can be calculated with sizeof()
} FileStruct_t;
```

sample file content:

```
[StructA identifier][StructA data][StructC identifier][StructC data]
```

or:

```
[StructB identifier][StructB data]
```

every combination (even multiple definitions of a type) needs to be possible by using something like this.

Like this, I want to save and read multiple structures in a file dynamically.

Can something like this be achieved?

---

**Update:** If I use struct labels as ID's or names,

How may I write the real struct to the file, not the pointer and after reading, how should I act? Will I need to create these read data structs globally in the memory?

---

To prevent misunderstanding, I'm going to save the data that structures contain to a file. Not the struct definition.

Comment: If you want to dynamically read different struct types from a file, you must precede every struct in the file with an identification, either a number or a name. Then read the data into the appropriate struct type.

Comment: Yes, I know that but is it possible to do it without using a identifier? like a pointer to get the struct?

Comment: I mean If I have 500 types of structs, I'll need to write a switch statement for every struct. I want to dynamicize the process.

Comment: @TahaPaksu: How about writing a smile Python script that will generate the code for you?

Comment: @nsilent22 how is this relevant? If it can't be done, say so. I just wondered if something like this is possible.

Comment: You can do this with some fancy macro usage.  I have similar things in the past by having a special header file that uses macros to both define the structure and also to allow reading and writing them.  It can make the code a little esoteric and difficult for others to understand though.  However if you do know how it works it can make maintaining and altering the code a lot simpler and more robust.  I'll put a quick example together.

Comment: @Wossname thank you very much.

Comment: You still need the identifier to precede the struct in the file. You still need to determine what struct is now coming. You can always automate the code generation by writing a program/macro bunch to generate the code  (more fun, but probably more work).

Comment: @TahaPaksu: Well, if I understand your code correctly you have to distinguish the struct type by `iStructType`. So if you want to save them correctly (e.g. save the *content* of member `b` of struct type `StructB_t`, not just the pointer value) you *have* to write code that treats this struct specially. By using some helper script I meant it could generate the code tying structures and identifiers together, and also generate the switch statement for calling correct save-function variant. But it's you who has to write the "meat" to fill them.

Comment: Yes, I accepted the need of a explicitly defined identifier. I'll write a custom save method to save the structure. And when I read, I understand that I'll need to read them all to a memory area and use them from there. Should I use UNIONs to collect all the different structs to one type?

Comment: Union'ing all types together would make the code a lot easier to manage but would waste some file storage space (I don't know if that's a problem for you or not).  You would still need to write specialised read-write functions in order to treat the union as the right struct in order to get sane data out of the file.

Comment: How many structs do you have?  I'm thinking my macro suggestion is only worth the effort if you have more than say 10 structs.

Comment: Well, yes it might be.But it'll give me the chance to use indexes. But linked lists might work as well. Someone write an answer and I'll accept that.

Comment: @Wossname, it'll extend in time. I'm writing a campaign module for an ECR, so it'll be containing different structure types for different kinds of campaigns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realise there was a wiki page for the thing I was referring to earlier...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro

Basically this technique will allow you to somewhat "standardise" the way you add new structures to your application without having to write the same kinds of functions over and over again.  The same macros that define the struct can be re-defined in order to perform the read/write the structs to files.

Conceptually you'd end up #including the same header file at least 3 times but each time you change the meaning of the macros called in the header file.  If harnessed correctly this can be an extremely powerful way to simplify large amounts of code that would otherwise be prone to human error to maintain.

What follows is an example program that shows how to create "x macros" to standardise interfacing with many structures that share a similar theme.

The "print_..." functions defined here are analogous to the functions that would read and write each kind of structure to a file in your program.

FILE: xm_struct_definers.h

```
#define XM_STRUCT_HEADER(xm_name_xm) typedef struct xmacros_##xm_name_xm xm_name_xm; \
                                     struct xmacros_##xm_name_xm {

#define XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_INT(xm_name_xm) int xm_name_xm;
#define XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_CHAR(xm_name_xm) char xm_name_xm;
#define XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_CHAR_STAR(xm_name_xm) char* xm_name_xm;
#define XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_LONG(xm_name_xm) long xm_name_xm;
#define XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_SHORT(xm_name_xm) short xm_name_xm;

#define XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_CUSTOM_T(xm_name_xm) CUSTOM_t xm_name_xm;


#define XM_STRUCT_FOOTER };
```

FILE: xm_structs.h

```
//THESE ARE ALL "X-MACRO" CALLS!
//They are defined and re-defined in multiple places in the program.
//Do not put "normal" C code in this file.

XM_STRUCT_HEADER(StructA_t)
XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_INT(a)
XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_CHAR(b)
XM_STRUCT_FOOTER

XM_STRUCT_HEADER(StructB_t)
XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_CUSTOM_T(a)
XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_CHAR_STAR(b)
XM_STRUCT_FOOTER

XM_STRUCT_HEADER(StructC_t)
XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_LONG(a)
XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_SHORT(b)
XM_STRUCT_FOOTER
```

FILE: xm_clear_macros.h

```
#undef XM_STRUCT_HEADER

#undef XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_INT
#undef XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_CHAR
#undef XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_CHAR_STAR
#undef XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_LONG
#undef XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_SHORT

#undef XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_CUSTOM_T

#undef XM_STRUCT_FOOTER
```

FILE: xm_struct_printers.h

```
#define XM_STRUCT_HEADER(xm_name_xm) void print_##xm_name_xm(xm_name_xm* record) {\
                                               printf("--STRUCT '"#xm_name_xm"'\n");

#define XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_INT(xm_name_xm)       printf("int   " #xm_name_xm ": %d\n", record->xm_name_xm);
#define XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_CHAR(xm_name_xm)      printf("char  " #xm_name_xm ": %c\n", record->xm_name_xm);
#define XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_CHAR_STAR(xm_name_xm) printf("char* " #xm_name_xm ": %s\n", record->xm_name_xm);
#define XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_LONG(xm_name_xm)      printf("long  " #xm_name_xm ": %ld\n", record->xm_name_xm);
#define XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_SHORT(xm_name_xm)     printf("short " #xm_name_xm ": %hd\n", record->xm_name_xm);

#define XM_STRUCT_MEMBER_CUSTOM_T(xm_name_xm)  printf("CUSTOM_T "#xm_name_xm":\n\t.x: %d\n\t.y: %d\n\t.z: %d\n" \
                                               , record->xm_name_xm.x, record->xm_name_xm.y, record->xm_name_xm.z);

#define XM_STRUCT_FOOTER                       printf("--END OF STRUCT\n\n");\
                                               }
```

FILE: main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
} CUSTOM_t;


//this is the first usage of the x macros...
//these actually create the definitions of the structures
#include "xm_struct_definers.h"
#include "xm_structs.h"
#include "xm_clear_macros.h"
//------------------------------

//this is the second usage of the x macros...
//which creates 3 functions that print out the contents of each type of structure
#include "xm_struct_printers.h"
#include "xm_structs.h"
#include "xm_clear_macros.h"
//------------------------------


int main()
{
  StructA_t sa;
  sa.a = 123;
  sa.b = 'A';

  StructB_t sb;
  sb.a.x = 1;
  sb.a.y = 2;
  sb.a.z = 3;
  sb.b = "BBBBB";

  StructC_t sc;
  sc.a = 123456789;
  sc.b = 10000;

  print_StructA_t(&sa);
  print_StructB_t(&sb);
  print_StructC_t(&sc);

  return 0;
}
```

To identify each type of structure (when it's stored in the file) you can simply add a "structType" integer to the end of the XM_STRUCT_HEADER() macro and use that as a key into a `switch(key){}` block that deals with each type correctly.

I wrote this using Ubuntu 15, you can compile on that platform with `gcc main.c -pedantic -std=gnu99 -o test` and then run with `./test`.

The output looks like:

```
--STRUCT 'StructA_t'
int   a: 123
char  b: A
--END OF STRUCT

--STRUCT 'StructB_t'
CUSTOM_T a:
        .x: 1
        .y: 2
        .z: 3
char* b: BBBBB
--END OF STRUCT

--STRUCT 'StructC_t'
long  a: 123456789
short b: 10000
--END OF STRUCT
```

Comment: I couldn't understand how I'm going to implement this method. Can you give an example for the structs in the question?

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding here. I need to save the data that previously defined structures contain, to a binary file. not a code file. I think you wrote this answer to create structure definitions in code files from somewhere else, right?

Comment: No, all you need to do is take the print_...() functions as a template and change them so that they do file reads and writes instead of printing to the screen.  I cannot write all your code for you, this is just a working example of how it could be done.  Examine my code in detail and understand the structure of it.  It can be extended to any number of new structures and methods.

Comment: No I don't want to write the code for me either. I'm here to learn new methods. I'll take a different approach I guess because this might be a overkill to what I'm trying to accomplish. I think I'll use the "append new structs to end" approach. Thank you so much for your efforts.

Comment: You're welcome.  But at least take a few minutes to look at the example.  It might be interesting if nothing else. :)  Good luck with your project.

Comment: Ok, I've looked at it. If I'm correct, The output of your code will be written to file, and when I read the file, I need to parse the string and call the relevant method to rebuild the structure data. But you're right, it'll give me the chance to change the order of the data. Also has this disadvantage, it'll save a char variable as a line containing min 6 redundant characters. But yes, it's a dynamic structure dumper/builder which has the capability of defining structures at runtime.

Comment: No, I think I have confused you.  I apologise.  The text that my program outputs is merely demonstrating that it is possible to access all the contents of the structures.  It is not intended to be the same as your data file.  I should have been clearer with my explanation.  You must still generate the code that reads and writes the file, but my code demonstrates a skeleton of how such a system may be generalised for future expansion.  If this answer proves too problematic please let me know and I'll delete it as it may be more of a hindrance than a solution.

Comment: No I didn't say that this answer is problematic, I've learnt much of it. Thanks. it can stay here for a reference for everybody. I'm going to look deeper later so this was my first impression thoughts. Thanks, really.